# Does there exist a continuous choice of maximizing balls for the Hardy Littlewood maximal function?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

*Note: Here $\overline B_r (x)$ denotes the closed ball of radius $r$ around $x$.*

Let $f \in L^1 (\mathbb R^d)$. We define the averages $A(x, r)$ for $x \in \mathbb R^d$ and $r > 0$ by

$$A(x, r) := \frac{1}{|B_r (x)|} \int_{B_r (x)} |f|.$$

**Question:** Do there exist continuous functions $c: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ and $r: \mathbb R^d \to [0, \infty)$ with the following property?

For each $x \in \mathbb R^d$, one of the following two conditions hold.

Either the supremum $\sup_{h, y; x \in \overline B_h (y)} A(h, y)$ is achieved at some point and we have

$$A(c(x), r(x)) = \sup_{h, y; \, x \in \overline B_h (y)} A(h, y),$$

or the supremum is not achieved, and we have $c(x) = x$ and $r = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general. You already can find an example in $d = 1$.

Let $f$ be given by the function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x\in [-1,0] \\
2 & x \in [4,5] \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

It is clear that for $x < 0$, the interval $[c(x)-r(x),c(x) + r(x)]$ should be of the form either $[x,0]$ or $[x,5]$. So let's see what happens.

Denote by $A_0(x) = \frac{1}{|x|} \int_x^0 f$ and $A_5(x) = \frac{1}{|5-x|} \int_x^5 f$ we find

$$ A_0(x) = \frac{1}{|x|}, \quad A_5(x) = \frac{3}{|5-x|} $$

These two functions cross when $x = -5/2$.

So you have that

- if $x < -5/2$, you have $r(x) = \frac{5-x}{2}$ and $c(x) = \frac{5+x}{2}$
- if $x \in (-5/2,0)$ you have $r(x) = \frac{|x|}{2}$ and $c(x) = \frac{x}{2}$

and so neither $c$ nor $r$ can be extended to a continuous function.

Comment: Nice example! I guess this can also be modified to be a continuous counterexample.